# Parts of speech in sentence "Amber is a real person"

Tags: nouns, adjectives, pronouns, parts-of-speech, proper-nouns

**Specifically I am wondering about the word "person" in the sentence**, because at first thought I believed it was a common noun but it is qualifying a proper noun, so I am confused if it is a noun or a adjective. If it is a noun what kind of noun is it?

Comment: "Person" is an ordinary common noun. What else could it be?

Comment: Why do you think "person" might be functioning as a verb? Can you say "I am personing?" Why do you think "person" isn't a common noun? What about "Paris is a city"? It's quite normal for a sentence to describe a proper noun in terms of the category (common noun) it belongs to. Can you explain where your confusion lies?

Comment: I intended to say adjective. I thought it might be because it's use in the sentence is conditional on describing amber.

Comment: It also does not meet any definition of "object of the sentence" that I can find. It is not affected by directly or indirectly, or introduced by amber.

Comment: After some research I believe "person" to be an adverbal noun. The reason behind my thinking is that the verb "is" in this sentence is a state of being verb, and not an action verb. The word "person" describes what state of being "amber" is.

Comment: @MichaelBosse No, it’s predicate noun.

Answer (score 1):

**Amber** = Subject of the sentence = (proper) noun.

**is** = verb of the sentence= (linking verb) verb.

**a real person** = object of the sentence = noun phrase, composed of:

1. A = indefinite article= adjective
2. real= adjective
3. person = (common) noun = modified by: *a* and *real*, the **head word** of said noun phrase.

Comment: This is mostly right, but copular verbs do not accept object complements. This NP is simply occurring predicatively. So the common noun *person* is a here being used as a predicate noun syntactically.

Comment: The articles "a" and "the" are not adjectives. They are determinatives functioning not as modifiers but as determiners. And the head word of the noun phrase is not the adj "real", but the noun"person". How can an adjective possibly be the head of a noun phrase?!

Answer (score 0):

Ambar [Proper Noun] is a real person [Common Noun].

Other examples of Proper Noun; Pakistan, Islam, Muslim.

Other examples of Common Noun; bird, animal, student.

In "I am a Muslim.", notice that the word "Muslim" is a common term and gives a general sense of some religion. However, it is a Proper (and not Common) Noun.

Comment: The OP states "Specifically I am wondering about the word *person* in the sentence" [my emphasis], but you haven't addressed this at all in your answer.

Comment: @chappo The answer very clearly says "person [Common Noun]."